# mongoose .js model without exporting ,requireing in anther folder still working it schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i have users.server.model file

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose'),
    Schema=mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema=new Schema({
    firstName:String,
    lastName:String,
    email:String,
    username:String,
    password:String
});
mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
```

requiring it in mongoose.js file

```
var config=require('./config'),
    mongoose=require('mongoose');
module.exports=function()
{
    var db=mongoose.connect(config.db);
//here i  require it.
//it is empty object because there is no export module in user.server.model
   require('../app/models/user.server.model');

    return db;
}
```

user.server.controll.js file.how the following User model know the Schema

```
    var User=require('mongoose').model('User');
    exports.create=function(req,res,next)
    {
        var user=new User(req.body);
        user.save(function(err){
            if(err){
                return next(err);
            }else{
                res.json(user);
            }
        });
    }
router file
var users=require('../../app/controllers/users.server.controller');
module.exports=function(app){
    app.route('/users').post(users.create).get(users.list);
}
```

express file

```
var config=require('./config');
var express=require('express');
var morgan=require('morgan');
var compress=require('body-parser');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var session=require('express-session');
var methodOverride=require('method-override');
module.exports=function(){
    var app=express();
    if(process.env.NODE_ENV=='development')
    {
            app.use(morgan('dev'));
    }
    else if(process.env.NODE_ENV==='production')
    {
        app.use(compress());
    }
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(methodOverride());
    app.use(session({
                        saveUninitialized: true,
                        resave: true,
                        secret: config.sessionSecret
            }));
    app.set('views','./app/views');
    app.set('view engine','ejs');
    require('../app/routes/index.server.routes.js')(app);
    require('../app/routes/users.server.routes.js')(app);
    app.use(express.static('./public'));
    return app; 
}
```

so my question is that
i am not exporting any thing in user.server.model file so who it know my schema
i just take this code from the book.(web mean development by Amos Q. Haviv) but it still working.how it work?

Answer (score 0):

mongoose.model('User',UserSchema); bind the schema into model and model is available by calling require('mongoose').model('User');