# how mongoose model works without exporting

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

user.server.model.js

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose'),
    Schema=mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema=new Schema({
    firstName:String,
    lastName:String,
    email:String,
    username:String,
    password:String
});
mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
```

mongoose.js file

```
var config=require('./config'),
    mongoose=require('mongoose');
module.exports=function()
{
    var db=mongoose.connect(config.db);
 require('../app/models/user.server.model');

    return db;
}
```

user.server.controller.js file

```
var User=require('mongoose').model('User');
exports.create=function(req,res,next)
{
    var user=new User(req.body);
    user.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            return next(err);
        }else{
            res.json(user);
        }
    });
}
```

user.server.routes.js

```
var users=require('../../app/controllers/users.server.controller');
module.exports=function(app){
    app.route('/users').post(users.create).get(users.list);
}
```

express.js

```
var config=require('./config');
var express=require('express');
var morgan=require('morgan');
var compress=require('body-parser');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var session=require('express-session');
var methodOverride=require('method-override');
module.exports=function(){
    var app=express();
    if(process.env.NODE_ENV=='development')
    {
            app.use(morgan('dev'));
    }
    else if(process.env.NODE_ENV==='production')
    {
        app.use(compress());
    }
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(methodOverride());
    app.use(session({
                        saveUninitialized: true,
                        resave: true,
                        secret: config.sessionSecret
            }));
    app.set('views','./app/views');
    app.set('view engine','ejs');
    require('../app/routes/index.server.routes.js')(app);
    require('../app/routes/users.server.routes.js')(app);
    app.use(express.static('./public'));
    return app; 
}
```

server.js

```
process.env.NODE_ENV=process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var mongoose=require('./config/mongoose');
    express=require('./config/express');
var db=mongoose();
var app=express();

app.listen(3000,function(){

    console.log('Listening on port '+3000 +" MODE "+process.env.NODE_ENV);
})

module.exports=app;
```

i didnt exported the mongoose model from user.server.model.js file how user.server.controller.js knows the mongoose model schema?? if i comment this {require('../app/models/user.server.model')} line in mongoose.js file the user schema gives error of schema not defined?
it works fine but explain how this example works.full code with question 
Example is taken from Mean Web Development in chapter 5 author Amos Q.Haviv.

Comment: It's a bit broad, but think in terms that mongoose itself has a "registry" of the defined "models" where you can use the latter syntax as you have to "recall" that model. Think dependency injection and service lookup. Of course you at least need to `require` the module at some stage for the code to be loaded at all, but there need not be an "export" for the declared model since there are built-in means to recall that object.

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681652/mongoose-js-model-without-exporting-requireing-in-anther-folder-still-working

Answer (score 0):

You are not requiring your mongoose.js but the mongoose module in your user.server.model.js. 
You could either use module.exports in the schema file but you don't want to do so or require your mongoose.js

```
var mongoose = require('./mongoose');
```

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking. What they are asking is *"Why does this work"* `var User=require('mongoose').model('User');` when the source "module" where this was defined is not "required" in the sense of `var User = require('./user.server.model')` and also that module has no `module.exports`. Understand?

Comment: Oh. Well I probably over read this one sentence.. Thanks :D